# deal with too many state

Tags: debugging, redux, state-machine

My question is pretty hard to explain, I'll try to explain it briefly :

I try to reproduce a timer like this timer in this website : https://cstimer.net/

The problem I have is : I have to deal with many "states" and many events :

the type of event I have is :

Chrono is not started -> I press "Space" -> The color becomes orange -> after 500ms -> chrono becomes green -> I release space -> chrono start -> I press space -> chrono stop

I would write the code which do that. The problem is that my code becomes very complicated because of too many "if".

```
if (!chronoIsStarted and SpaceIsPressed) { chrono.color = orange }
if (lastKeyDown - lastKeyUp >= 500 and !chronoIsStarted) { chrono.color = green }
if (keyup == space and lastKeyDown - lastKeyUp >= 500) { chono.start(); }

...
...
```

This is horrible because I have to have flag variable to prevent chrono to stop directly after start.

I'm looking to a way to manage that properly.

I heard about finite machine state, I don't know if it's a good solution.

Currently, I use react / redux and jquery for events, but I can add any libraries which can help.

Thanks you

Comment: You should be deciding the color in your reducers. You should also not be using React and jQuery together, particularly for handling events. If that doesn't make sense, I would go read the React and Redux docs thoroughly before continuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS). RxJS is a reactive library allowing you to manipulate asynchronous streams. In your particular example it could help to keep your code declarative and keeps it from being cluttered with global state.

For an introduction, check out the egghead.io course here: https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-what-is-rxjs

or check out this introduction to reactive programming: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

For example in your case, take a look at this fiddle from which you can make more complicated examples: http://jsfiddle.net/bryanph/5rkbxgtj/

```
// press space for clickSpace event
// hold space for holdSpace event

var chrono = {
   isStarted: false
}

document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"

var spaceUp = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.body, 'keyup')
    .filter(x => x.keyCode === 32)

var spaceDown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.body, 'keydown')
    .filter(e => e.keyCode === 32)
  .filter(e => !e.repeat)
  .partition(x => chrono.isStarted)

var chronoStarted = spaceDown[0];
var chronoStopped = spaceDown[1];

var clickSpace = chronoStopped.flatMap(function(e) {
    return spaceUp.timeout(200, Rx.Observable.empty())
})

var holdSpace = chronoStopped
        .flatMap(function(e) {
        return Rx.Observable
          .return(e)
          .delay(500)
          .takeUntil(spaceUp)
          .take(1)
    })

clickSpace.subscribe(function(x) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "orange"
})

holdSpace.subscribe(function(x) {
    console.log('called')
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a good, clear approach to solve my problem. I'll try to do something good with it :)